# I have to wait till the data load in combo box in java(selenium webdriver).I need syntax for this

Tags: java, selenium

In my application I have combo box, I need to wait till the data load in it. What syntax should I use for this? I used Thread.sleep()/implicit wait, but sometime it may not wait till loading. Is there any other syntax should I use? Please help me out this. Thanks in advance

```
String[] Modifierlist1 ={"25", "59", "51", "LT","RT",};
String Modifierrandomlist1 = Modifierlist1[new Random().nextInt(Modifierlist1.length)];
Select mod = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cboMod1Code")));
mod.selectByVisibleText(Modifierrandomlist1);
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Comment: Put some of your relevant code.

Comment: String[] Modifierlist1 ={"25", "59", "51", "LT","RT",}; String Modifierrandomlist1 = Modifierlist1[new Random().nextInt(Modifierlist1.length)];
  
  Select mod = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cboMod1Code")));
  mod.selectByVisibleText(Modifierrandomlist1);
  Thread.sleep(4000);

Comment: From your code it looks like you're trying to select from the combo-box before you've waited, why? Surely if you want to ensure that the contents is there so you can select it, you should wait before you make that selection?

Comment: Mark in my application I have 2 combo box.First When I select the one of the value in one combo box(25,59,51 etc),it display its corresponding description in another combo box.So I have to wait till the 2nd combo box gets loaded.Some time it loads correct but some time it is not getting loaded.If it is not loaded next line of the code gets run. Thank for your reply.This is my scenario.Help me out of this pls

Comment: @ArunKumar Did you try using a `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(secondBox, "text of last item"))`?

Comment: No I dont know how to use it.Can you tell me.I am new to Selenium...

Comment: @ArunKumar `WebdriverWait wait = new WebdriverWait(driver, "30"));
wait.until(ExcepectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(driver.findElement(By.id("secondComboBox")), "Visible Text of Last Option"))` Is a basic working example, the documentation is golden, read it. http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Java Swing Worker](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html&ei=goZeUpSzNYvJrAf66IDICw&usg=AFQjCNG29feo3-eEAANENlyaCeEKfP2xtQ&sig2=Fxz94VRBEu14rvXnWumdRg&bvm=bv.54176721,d.bmk) to do computation and then update your gui.

Answer (score 0):

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a")));
// it will wait until that xpath is visible